# How do I set multiple values to the same key without overwriting previous value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Basically I want to be able to add multiple values for a single key by placing said values into an array and setting it to my main object to access later. How can I best go about doing this? It's been so frustrating and I'm feeling discouraged and asking myself why I ever thought I can do this.

```
let mainObj = {}


const func = (str, obj) => {
  mainObj[str] = [obj]
}

func('str1', {content: 'content1' } )
func('str2', {content: 'content2' } )
func('str2', {content: 'content3' } )

console.log(mainObj)

//instead of this:
{ str1: [ { content: 'content1' } ],
  str2: [ { content: 'content3' } ] }


//I want this:
{ 
  str1: [ { content: 'content1' } ],
  str2: [ {content: 'content2' }, { content: 'content3' } ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if there is already array with that string key first;

if yes, then you push it to that array instead of replaceing it with new one,

if no, then doing what you were doingm creating an array with that key

```js
let mainObj = {}


const func = (str, obj) => {
  if (mainObj[str]){
    mainObj[str].push(obj)
  }else{
    mainObj[str] = [obj]
  }
}

func('str1', {content: 'content1' } )
func('str2', {content: 'content2' } )
func('str2', {content: 'content3' } )

console.log(mainObj)

//instead of this:
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make an array of it like this:

```js
const func = (str, obj) => {
  mainObj[str] = (mainObj[str] || []).concat([obj])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should push onto the element rather than overwriting it.

```js
let mainObj = {}

const func = (str, obj) => {
  if (!mainObj[str]) {
    mainObj[str] = [];
  }
  mainObj[str].push(obj);
}

func('str1', {
  content: 'content1'
})
func('str2', {
  content: 'content2'
})
func('str2', {
  content: 'content3'
})

console.log(mainObj)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! I need to relax and think programatically